Train neural network for Absolute function with minimum Layers
I'm trying to train neural network to learn y = |x| function. As we know the absolute function has 2 different lines connecting with each other at point zero. So I'm trying to have following Sequential model:
Hidden Layer:
2 Dense Layer (activation relu)
Output Layer:
1 Dense Layer
after training the model,it only fits the half side of the function. Most of the time it is right hand side, sometimes it is the left side. As soon as I add 1 more Layer in the hidden layer, so instead of 2 I have 3, it perfectly fits the function. Can anyone explain why there is need an extra layer when the absolute function has only one cut ?
Here is the code:
import numpy as np


X = np.linspace(-1000,1000,400)
np.random.shuffle(X)
Y = np.abs(X)

# Reshape data to fit the model input
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000)
# Predict using the model
Y_pred = model.predict(X)

# Plot the results
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='blue', label='Actual')
plt.scatter(X, Y_pred, color='red', label='Predicted')
plt.title('Actual vs Predicted')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Plot for 2 Dense Layer:

Plot for 3 Dense Layer:


Probably just an initialization issue. If both units are initialized on the "same side" (i.e. both have the same sign for their weights), they can never switch because no gradient is received for the other side (due to the hard 0 output). It should actually work in 50% of the cases or so. With  more layers, this becomes less likely to happen, as you effectively have more units, so the chance that all are "on the same side" reduces exponentially.

so you mean because relu outputs 0 for the second perceptron for example, it will never update it because it's 0 and will only focus on the first one?

Not quite, but basically, in this simple setup, if both hidden units are initialized on the same "side", e.g. both with a positive weight, they will only activate for positive inputs. Thus they can learn the correct activation for the positive inputs, but not for the negative ones (because there they always have a negative activation, which is rectified to 0, and no gradient). Basically, you have two hidden units performing the same task, so it would be the same as just having one hidden unit, which cannot learn the abs function.

It depends on the weight initialization.
If both weights of are initilized with positive numbers, the network can only predict positive numbers. For negative numbers, it will always output zero.
This will also result no gradients - there is no small step to the weights that would make the output match a bit better.
So either switch to a different activation function, such as leaky Relu that also passes some signal for the negative values or change the init.
In the code below I demonstrate it with different custom inits.
good_init sets one weight to a positive, one to a negative values -> The problem gets solved.
both bad_inits set the weights to the same sign, and only half of the domain will be learned.
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(-1000,1000,400)
np.random.shuffle(X)
Y = np.abs(X)

# Reshape data to fit the model input
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

from keras import backend as K

def good_init(shape, dtype=None):
    # one positive, one negative weight
    val=np.linspace(-1,1,np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
    return K.variable(value=val, dtype=dtype)

def bad_init_right(shape, dtype=None):
    # both weights positive, only right side works
    val=np.linspace(-1,1,np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
    val=np.abs(val)
    return K.variable(value=val, dtype=dtype)


def bad_init_left(shape, dtype=None):
    # both weights negative, only right side works
    val=np.linspace(-1,1,np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
    val=-np.abs(val)
    return K.variable(value=val, dtype=dtype)

# Build the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=bad_init_left),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100)
# Predict using the model
Y_pred = model.predict(X)

# Plot the results
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='blue', label='Actual')
plt.scatter(X, Y_pred, color='red', label='Predicted')
plt.title('Actual vs Predicted')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


you nailed it thank you!, one last question, and why adding the layers is helping the model then ?

If you add a third neuron,
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu') ->  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='relu')
you increase the probabilities of having weight with both signs from 50% to 75%.

With 2 dense layers, you essentially have an input and an output layer. Going by your code, you only have two layer but no hidden layers in your model. That allows you to approximate functions of the 1st degree, e.g. lines for classification, regression, etc. The gradient is only calculated twice per iteration giving you essentially two anchor points - great for lines, not so great for parables.
If you add one more layer, you now have a hidden layer between input and output. That allows for more complex modelling because the gradient is calculated thrice now per iteration. Generally it used to approximate functions of the second order, e.g. x^2 and the like.
np.abs(x) is similar to a parable and needs a three layer model. If you are interested in how and why neural networks work, there is a very good course on Coursera from Andrew Ng "Machine Learning". It's free if you don't want the certificate.

It's not actually like this because in the code above the first Dense layer is a hidden layer (and input data is basically an input layer and last Dense layer is output layer). To reproduce situation you described we need NN with only 1 Dense layer.  It seems that solution for this particular question is described in the first comment under the post, we can simply check it using tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(seed) with different seed values.

No, the model above has only two defined layers. The first dense layer must be the input layer. There is no additional input layer defined anywhere.

Thanks for the response @emely_pi, but the first layer is a hidden layer, because the input layer is configured automatically and that's why it's not written here, so I have
Input layer => Dense Layer with 2 outputs => 1 output layer
so with the middle layer it should be able to approximate x^2 functions,
If that wasn't the case I would get an error because the shape of the first layer with 2 inputs wouldn't match the X shape which has a single input
